SVG Circular Progress bar to complete progress by defined value
I am creating one SVG Circular Progress bar. It is working, But when i pass some value, Hence based on that value it is not completing the progress.
Below is the code, Which i tried so far


    window.addEventListener("load", function
(event){
  let progressbar = document.querySelectorAll('.progress-bar');
  progressbar.forEach(function(circle){
    let degree = 0;
    let percentage=0;
    var targetDegree = parseInt(circle.getAttribute('data-degree'));
      var element = circle.children;
       var childElem = element.item(1);
      let color = circle.getAttribute('data-color'); 
       let number = document.querySelector('.text');
       let childNumber = document.querySelector('.totalfilling'); 
       var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
         degree+=1;
         if(percentage >= 1){ 
         clearInterval(interval);
           return; 
         } 
         percentage = degree/targetDegree ;
         var progressCalc = 848 - (848 * targetDegree) / 100;
     
      //childElem.style = `stroke-dashoffset: calc(${progressCalc})`;
        childElem.style.background = `conic-gradient( 
         ${color} ${percentage*100}%, #222 0%)`;
         number.innerHTML = degree;
         number.style.color =  color;
        childNumber.innerHTML = '<h5>'+targetDegree+'</h5>'
      },50)
  });
});
body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .center {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background: rgb(25, 25, 50);
      }
      .progress {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        border-radius: 5mm;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        position: relative;
      }
      circle {
        fill: none;
      }
      svg {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
      }
      circle:nth-child(1) {
        stroke: rgb(240, 248, 255);
        stroke-width: 12px;
      }
      circle:nth-child(2) {
        stroke: rgb(78, 91, 205);
        stroke-dasharray: 848;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-width: 16px;
        animation: progress 1s ease;
      }
      @keyframes progress {
        from {
          stroke-dashoffset: 848;
        }
      }
      .text {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        font-family: poppins;
        font-size: 60px;
        color: rgb(78, 91, 205);
        font-weight: 500;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .text span {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: rgb(78, 91, 205);
      }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Circular Progress Bar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="center">
      <div class="progress">
        <svg class="progress-bar" data-degree="75" data-color="#0b60e9" width="300" height="300">
          <circle class="progress-circle" cx="150" cy="150" r="135"></circle>
          <circle class="progress-circle" cx="150" cy="150" r="135"></circle>
           <div class="text">
          75
          <span>Completed</span>
        </div>
        <div class="totalfilling">
                    <h5>1000</h5>
                </div>
        </svg>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



In the above code i tried to use some max value, So the progress bar should complete based on the max value.
But this logic is not working.
Need help.

So, basically if I good understanding your task, stroke doesn’t fill circle to value, right?
If so, try change way how you calculate percentage.
percentage = degree / 100;

And then in relation to that adjust stroke-dashoffset
Thing is that interval has to stop when the degree reaches the targetDegree
if (degree >= targetDegree) {
  clearInterval(interval);
  return;
}



    window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
    let progressbar = document.querySelectorAll('.progress-bar');
    progressbar.forEach(function (circle) {
      let degree = 0;
      let percentage = 0;
      const targetDegree = parseInt(circle.getAttribute('data-degree'));
      const maxDegrees = 100;
      const circumference = 848;
      const element = circle.children;
      const childElem = element.item(1);
      const color = circle.getAttribute('data-color');
      const number = document.querySelector('.text');
      const childNumber = document.querySelector('.totalfilling');

      var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (degree >= targetDegree) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          return;
        }
        degree += 1;
        percentage = degree / targetDegree;
        const progressCalc = circumference - (circumference * percentage);
        childElem.style.strokeDashoffset = progressCalc;
        childElem.style.stroke = color;
        number.innerHTML = degree;
        number.style.color = color;
        childNumber.innerHTML = '<h5>' + targetDegree + '</h5>';
      }, 50);
    });
  });
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .center {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rgb(25, 25, 50);
  }
  .progress {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 5mm;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
  }
  circle {
    fill: none;
  }
  svg {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  circle:nth-child(1) {
    stroke: rgb(240, 248, 255);
    stroke-width: 12px;
  }
  circle:nth-child(2) {
    stroke: rgb(78, 91, 205);
    stroke-dasharray: 848;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-width: 16px;
  }
  .text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-family: poppins;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: rgb(78, 91, 205);
    font-weight: 500;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .text span {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: rgb(78, 91, 205);
  }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Circular Progress Bar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="center">
  <div class="progress">
    <svg class="progress-bar" data-degree="135" data-color="#0b60e9" width="300" height="300">
      <circle class="progress-circle" cx="150" cy="150" r="135"></circle>
      <circle class="progress-circle" cx="150" cy="150" r="135"></circle>
    </svg>
    <div class="text">
      75
      <span>Completed</span>
    </div>
    <div class="totalfilling">
      <h5>1000</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>




Thank you for the suggested code, When i set data degree value to more than 100 e.g: 125 then it starts the progress but for completing progress to 125 it's override the progress, Which is not correct. It should complete the progress based on the provided value. So i did one line of change in script file in this line: percentage = degree / maxDegrees; //instead maxDegrees, Used targetDegree variable and it started working as exptected. Kindly do the same change in your answer as well.

If you use the pathLength attribute on the circle it is easier to calculate the stroke-dasharray and offset.
Don't use HTML inside the SVG element. In this case you can use the <text> element.


let progressbar = document.querySelectorAll('.progress-bar');
progressbar.forEach(function(circle) {
  let degree = 0;
  let percentage = 0;
  let targetDegree = parseInt(circle.dataset.degree);
  let childElem = circle.querySelector('circle:nth-child(2)');
  let number = circle.querySelector('.text');
  let childNumber = circle.querySelector('.totalfilling');
  childNumber.innerHTML = targetDegree;
  number.style.color = circle.dataset.color;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    degree += 1;
    if (degree >= targetDegree) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    childElem.style.strokeDashoffset = degree - 100;
    number.innerHTML = degree;
  }, 50)
});
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.center {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: rgb(25, 25, 50);
}

.progress {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 5mm;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

circle {
  fill: none;
}

circle:nth-child(1) {
  stroke: rgb(240, 248, 255);
  stroke-width: 12px;
}

circle:nth-child(2) {
  stroke: rgb(78, 91, 205);
  stroke-dasharray: 848;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 16px;
}

.text {
  font-family: poppins;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 500;
  fill: rgb(78, 91, 205);
  font-weight: 500;
}
<div class="center">
  <div class="progress">
    <svg class="progress-bar" data-degree="75"
      data-color="#0b60e9" width="320" height="300">
      <g transform="translate(150 150)">
        <circle class="progress-circle" r="135"></circle>
        <circle class="progress-circle" transform="rotate(90)"
          r="135" pathLength="100" stroke-dasharray="100 100"></circle>
        <text class="text" dominant-baseline="middle"
          text-anchor="middle"></text>
      </g>
      <text class="totalfilling" font-size="20" x="320" y="150"
      dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="end">test</text>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>




I have adjusted the javascript to run the progress based on the percentage increase.


window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
        let progressBars = document.querySelectorAll('.progress-bar');
        progressBars.forEach(function(circle) {
                let targetDegree = parseInt(circle.getAttribute('data-degree'));
                let radius = circle.querySelector('.progress-circle').getAttribute('r');
                let circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
                let offset = circumference - (targetDegree / 100) * circumference;

                circle.querySelector('.progress-circle:nth-child(2)').style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} ${circumference}`;
                circle.querySelector('.progress-circle:nth-child(2)').style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
                let number = document.querySelector('.text');

                let degree = 0;
                let percentage = 0;                 
                var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
                        degree += 1;
                        if(degree >= targetDegree){ 
                                clearInterval(interval);
                                number.innerHTML = targetDegree; // Set the final value to targetDegree
                                return; 
                        } 
                        percentage = (degree / targetDegree) * 100;
                        number.innerHTML = Math.round(percentage);      
                        number.style.color = circle.getAttribute('data-color');
                }, 10);
        });
});
body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .center {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background: rgb(25, 25, 50);
      }
      .progress {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        border-radius: 5mm;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        position: relative;
      }
      circle {
        fill: none;
      }
      svg {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
      }
      circle:nth-child(1) {
        stroke: rgb(240, 248, 255);
        stroke-width: 12px;
      }
      circle:nth-child(2) {
        stroke: rgb(78, 91, 205);
        stroke-dasharray: 848;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-width: 16px;
        animation: progress 1s ease;
      }
      @keyframes progress {
        from {
          stroke-dashoffset: 848;
        }
      }
      .text {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        font-family: poppins;
        font-size: 60px;
        color: rgb(78, 91, 205);
        font-weight: 500;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .text span {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: rgb(78, 91, 205);
      }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Circular Progress Bar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="center">
      <div class="progress">
        <svg class="progress-bar" data-degree="75" data-color="#0b60e9" width="300" height="300">
          <circle class="progress-circle" cx="150" cy="150" r="135"></circle>
          <circle class="progress-circle" cx="150" cy="150" r="135"></circle>
            <div class="text">
              75
              <span>Completed</span>
            </div>
            <div class="totalfilling">
                <h5>100</h5>
            </div>
        </svg>       
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



