make scale circle progress bar
I need to create a scale circle progress bar, Where i need to have the progress bar design like this 
I have done so far to reach out the same design, But couldn't.


let count=0, interval = setInterval(change, 50)
        function change(){
            count++;
            if(count===100) clearInterval(interval)
            document.getElementById('c2').style.strokeDashoffset = 1257 + 1257 -((count/100) * 1257) + 'px'
            document.getElementById('rate').innerHTML = count + '%';
        }
*
    {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .container{
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 100px auto;
        position: relative;
    }
    svg{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
    #c1{
        stroke: rgb(39,62,83);
        fill: none;
        stroke-width:30px;
        stroke-dasharray: 12.57px;
    }
    #c2{
        stroke: white;
        fill: none;
        stroke-width:35px;
        stroke-dasharray: 1257px;
        stroke-dashoffset: 600px;
    }
    #rate{
        position: absolute;
        inset:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        font-family:arial;
        font-size: 100px;
        color: aquamarine;
        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;
    }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Circular Progress Bar with scale</title>
    
    </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <svg>
            <circle id="c1" cx="250" cy="250" r="200"></circle>
            <circle id="c2" cx="250" cy="250" r="200"></circle>
        </svg>
        <div id="rate">
           5%
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



As we can see in this image progress bar is starting from around 30 degree and completing by 150 degree. Also used arrow here.
There is one condition here like: based on the provided max value progress bar should complete the progress.
Need help.

Please add your code as a snippet. The js fiddle link is also missing

If the problem is where it starts & ends, where should it start and end?

Have look at chrwahl's previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78578995/svg-circular-progress-bar-to-complete-progress-by-defined-value#78579561. In short: better use pathLength to simplify the dash-array calculation.

Indeed using "pathLength=100" on the circles will make this a lot easier, because all stroke-dash settings will become a 0 to 100 range. And my advice would be to skip the CSS (for now) and do it all in SVG first. Once you (almost) have what you need in a static SVG you can offload (duplicate) SVG attribute settings to CSS.. need be JavaScript. FYI; the animation can be done in SVG too, its called SMIL. But not many good learning resources around apart from SO answers

Please also take the time to follow the recommended links from previous questions to posts like "Simple svg css progress circle" before posting similar subsequent questions. That's probably why your post was downvoted (... to be honest I was also considering it).  You also find examples for your case. This style of progress bar is also referred to as "horse-shoe" gauge/progress bar etc.

@danny I always thought David Dailey's SMIL/SVG learning resources were rather good.

Yes, there are some, but you have to dig thru a lot of Google results. A very very recent good one (on morphing paths) is: https://minus-ze.ro/posts/morphing-arbitrary-paths-in-svg/

As mentioned in the comments it is easier to calculate the value of the bar (blue circle) if you set the pathLength. Here I use 133 (ok, 133.5 because the blue circle is just a bit too long when it shows 100%) because you need 100% to be equal to 3/4 of the circle.
For the "threshold" its a bit more complicated in that I rotate the elements, it is the 360 degrees that apply. But 3/4 of a full circle is 270, so you just need to divide 270 by 100.


const c1 = document.getElementById('c1');
const t1 = document.getElementById('t1');
const g1 = document.getElementById('g1');
const t2 = document.getElementById('t2');

document.forms.form01.val.addEventListener('change', e => {
  c1.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', 100 - e.target.valueAsNumber);
  t1.textContent = e.target.valueAsNumber;
});

document.forms.form01.tval.addEventListener('input', e => {
  g1.setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${270 / 100 * e.target.valueAsNumber})`);
  t2.textContent = e.target.valueAsNumber;
});
body {
  display: flex;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

circle#c1 {
  transition: stroke-dashoffset ease-in-out 1s;
}
<svg height="90vh" viewBox="0 0 100 110" fill="none">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="lg1" x1="0.7" gradientTransform="rotate(45)">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#eee" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ddd" />
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="m1">
      <circle transform="rotate(135)" stroke="white"
        stroke-width="12" r="44" stroke-dasharray="270 360"
        pathLength="360"/>
    </mask>
    <radialGradient id="rg1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#aaa" />
      <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#ccc" />
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="white" />
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  <ellipse cx="50" cy="102" rx="40" ry="8" fill="url(#rg1)" />
  <g transform="translate(50 50)">
    <circle stroke="#eee" stroke-width="12" r="44"/>
    <g mask="url(#m1)">
      <rect transform="translate(-50 -50)" width="100" height="100"
        fill="url(#lg1)" />
      <circle stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="12" r="44"
        stroke-dasharray=".5 4.5" pathLength="360" pathLength="360"/>
      <circle stroke="#bbb" stroke-width="6" r="41"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="rotate(135)">
      <circle id="c1" stroke="SteelBlue" stroke-width="8" r="42"
        stroke-dasharray="100 133" pathLength="133.5" stroke-dashoffset="25"/>
    </g>
    <line transform="rotate(45) translate(38 0)" stroke="#aaa"
      stroke-width="1" x2="12" />
    <line transform="rotate(135) translate(38 0)" stroke="#aaa"
      stroke-width="1" x2="12" />
    <g id="g1" transform="rotate(216)">
      <line transform="rotate(-225) translate(38 0)" stroke="#000"
        stroke-width=".5" x2="12" />
      <polygon transform="rotate(-225) translate(36 0)"
        points="0,-4.5 0,4.5 5,0" fill="#000"/>
    </g>
    <text id="t1" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20" font-weight="400"
      text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" fill="SteelBlue">75</text>
    <text id="t2" y="10" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9"
      font-weight="400" text-anchor="start" dominant-baseline="hanging" fill="#000">80</text>
  </g>
</svg>
<form name="form01">
  <lable>Value: <input name="val" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="75"/></lable>
  <lable>Threshold: <input name="tval" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="80"/></lable>
</form>




Thank you for the design, You have implemented the same as i expected. I just need to make the progress bar dynamic, So it should complete it by it's provided value by the user, For threshold logic i need to look into closely.

@Vicky I updated my answer, so that the progress bar now has a transition on the stroke-dashoffset. Is this more in line with you requirements?

Here is a little change in the logic. We have here one max value e.g: 100 which we are showing as black font. Threshold value is the target value e.g: 80. So when user click on button or something then the progress has to be complete till threshold value only. It should not go till 100 (max value). Also here user can provide max value and target value more than 100 as well. I have created one fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vikashfiddle/j6ho1yn7/32/

Kindly help me to get the same. Thank you.
